# Want normal back button functionality of browser while loading pages with ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have developing web application in php and used **ajax request's to get page** from server
example on click of menu tabs ajax request a page from server and load it into a specific **HTMl div** of **index.php** . so always all the pages get in **index.php specific htmi div.**

So on click of browser back button it always remains on default page. how can i enable browser back/forward button functionality so that it will maintain previous page states

Comment: You're looking for the HTML5 History API.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the HTML5 History API provides the functionality you're looking for, but if you must support browsers without a guarantee that those browsers will support the History API, take a look at the [jQuery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), it'll get you where you need to go.  The important point to remember is that you're going to be using the URL hashtag to record "page loads" that are only really ajax loads.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick, but I haven't tested:

```
(function($, window) {
    function supports_history_api() {
        return !!(window.history && history.pushState);
    }

    if (!supports_history_api()) { return; }  // Doesn't support so return

    function swapContent(href) {
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            cache: false
        }).done(function( data ) {
            var parser = $("#parser"); //Some empty and hidden element for parsing
            parser.html(data);

            var parsed = parser.find(".container").contents(), //Get the loaded stuff
                realContainer = $(".container").first(); //This one wasn't loaded

            realContainer.html(parsed);
            parser.contents().remove(); //Empty the div again
        });
    }

    $(".aTag").on("click", function(e) { //Select the links to do work on
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        swapContent(href);
        e.preventDefault();
        history.pushState(null, null, href); //Push state to history, check out HTML 5 History API
    });

    window.onpopstate = function() {
        swapContent(location.href);
    };
})(jQuery, window);
```

Some HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="aTag" href="tiles_1.html"><img src="img/tiles_1.jpg" /></a>
    <a class="aTag" href="tiles_2.html"><img src="img/tiles_2.jpg" /></a>
    <a class="aTag" href="tiles_3.html"><img src="img/tiles_3.jpg" /></a>
    <a class="aTag" href="tiles_4.html"><img src="img/tiles_4.jpg" /></a>
</div>

//Loaded content gets pushed here for parsing
<div id="parser" style="display:none;"></div>
```